# delete variable of doublons on 3 row

Tags: r

I got a problem with my data.   I explain me:

I got a data with 10 varialbes.  For example, I have the ID, the mail and the note of questions.    On 3 row I got the same name, the same Email but not the same notes.  So that's not really a doublon but a triplon.
[image]

So I would like just get the first row and not the 2 row who are below.

thank you

Comment: `df %>% group_by(id, mail) %>% slice(1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data loaded into a `data.table`, e.g. using `fread()` or casting the `data.frame` to using `as.data.table()` you can then use the `unique()` function to get the first row for each user ID:

```
dt <- fread("path/to/file.txt")
dt <- unique(dt, by="id")
```

Comment: I tried to do unique(data1, by="id")   but i got exactely the same data with the same number of rows